# How to rotate an image based on text within it to revert it back to its original orientation?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, google-cloud-vision

so I am writing a program that requires the image to be aligned properly for accurate ocr extraction. The problem is, however, in my image directory, lots of images are rotated in random multiples of 90 degrees. How or what can I use to rotate them back to their original orientation?

Here is a sample image:

[image]

The fields of interest are at the top right corner.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use `image_to_osd` method of `pytesseract` which corrects the text orientation given that you have rotation with 90 degrees. `text = pytesseract.image_to_osd('path/to/image.jpeg')`. This shall work for you.

Comment: Sample a small square 1/10th of the way in from each corner. The two with redness belong at the bottom.